# Автоматический импорт в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Случайными манипуляциями автоматический импорт класса Scanner вместо стандартного util импортирует другой. Где можно найти настройки в Intellij IDEA, редактирующие эту конфигурацию предлагаемого выбора классов для импортирования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Intellij IDEA предусмотрен поиск по настройкам. File - Settings, в верхнем левом углу вбиваете import и видите Editor - General - Autoimport. Здесь все настройки, связанные с авто импортом